# ExecCommand in Meteor is not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, contenteditable, rich-text-editor, execcommand

I'm trying to implement the basic Rich Text Editing functionalities of ContentEditable in Meteor and I'm having an issue with execCommand.
The undo and redo commands work fine but every other command such as bold and italic do not work and give out no errors.
The code also worked fine as a regular page (I've done the obvious adaptations for Meteor such as templates and the events).

My html:

```
<body>
    {{> buttons}}
  <div id="editor" class="textZone" contenteditable="true"></div>
</body>

<template name="buttons">

    <div id="rtfOptions">
        <div class="separate">
            <div class="rtfOption" id="undo">undo</div>
            <div class="rtfOption" id="redo">redo</div>
        </div>

        <div class="separate">
            <div class="rtfOption" id="bold">bold</div>
            <div class="rtfOption" id="italic">italic</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

My events (only 2 non-working + the undo as it works. As for the rest its pretty much the same):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
        Template.buttons.events({
                "click #bold": function() { // Toggles bold on/off for the selection or at the insertion point
                    document.execCommand("bold", false, "null");
                },
                "click #italic": function() { // Toggles italics on/off for the selection or at the insertion point
                    document.execCommand("italic", false, "null");
                },
                "click #undo": function() { // Undoes the last executed command.
                    document.execCommand('undo', false, "null");
                }
    )};
}
```

Someone know the issue? Does it have something to do with document or the scope?

Comment: `"null"` is wrong. It should be just `null` without the quotation marks. However, I'm not sure that would make any difference. Is your editor using an iframe for the editor content?

Comment: No, that doesn't make any difference. I had it just as null before and I simply was testing if that was it because of my linter.

I am not using an iframe and I specifically don't want to.

Comment: OK. There's no obvious reason why it wouldn't work then.

Comment: There is no more code other than the other ExecCommands that are the same as the three above but for other options.
The only thing i left out (I think) is that this is running in a if(Meteor.isClient) block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the `div` tags to `button` instead (for the clickable elements), or make the div text unselectable (e.g disabling `user-select` with css) it should work as you expect.

The reason is that when you click on the `div` with text inside, the `execCommand` targets the `div`'s text (which is not `contenteditable`) so the command fails silently. Try adding `contenteditable="true"` to the div and you'll see that it will bold the `div`'s text if you click on it. Alternatively, try adding the css rule `-webkit-user-select: none;` (on Chrome, vendor prefixes differ on other browsers) to disable text selection on the div, and you'll see that the `execCommand` works just fine.

See a working demo [here](http://edit-example.meteor.com).

Code examples, for clarity:

**Option 1**

```
<template name="buttons">
  <div id="rtfOptions">
    <div class="separate">
      <div class="rtfOption" id="bold" style="user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;">bold</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Option 2**

```
<template name="buttons">
  <div id="rtfOptions">
    <div class="separate">
      <button class="rtfOption" id="bold">bold</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I have contenteditable="true" in the div. It's in the code above.
The -webkit-user-select: none; did not work.

Comment: @mesosteros See my edit -- I think I was being unclear. I meant that if you added `contenteditable="true"` to the clickable `div` elements (the ones with the id's) you'll see that the bolding occurs on those divs' text -- implying that the issue is that `execCommand` is being eaten up by the text inside those `divs`. The solution is to either change the `div` tags to buttons or use the css rule.